# how to fix ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.6.0?

Tags: android

actually i'm still a beginer on android studio. i tried using the default android 4.4 but when i add some implementation on the build.gradle the notification says failed to resolve: com.google.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.6.0. i've been trying some advice and some tutorial but still can't resolve the problem.
Here is the code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.arcraw"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation'com.google.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.6.0'
    implementation'com.karumi:dexter:6.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Sceneform overview](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform), you should change the line in gradle file from

```
implementation'com.google.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.6.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.6.0'
```

**Update:** The latest version is `1.14.0`, just in case you want to use it

```
implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.14.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this issue is fixed in 1.9.0 version or you can use latest version 1.14.0

try

```
implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.14.0
```

Answer (score 0):

As in [1]: https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk
you can see that google **abounded** sceneform android sdk
and the library is archived as they said : This repository has been archived and is no longer maintained.

status: inactive